# use mosspy to check the code similarity in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbNpx.png)

Try to use mosspy lib to check similarity of the code file, but when I input exactly same file, it still show me the result "no match", can I know what happen here?

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Ifk.png)

Comment: I think it is hard for the community to answer your question because some information is missing. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocodeforreview/ and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Please format your pose correctly and add more details